# How to use context object to share data between resolvers using F# GraphQL?

Tags: f#, graphql

I am writing a GraphQL server in F# using [FSharp.Data.GraphQL](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.GraphQL). I am well versed in GraphQL using Node.js libraries. The standard practice to share data between resolvers is using `context` object.

However, I could not find any such example or documentation to do so. Is there any way to achieve this?